# How to query a polymorphic Eloquent model providing the type and the id?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic model `Discussion` and other models that are `discussable`.

I have configured my morph map to translate `project` to `App\Models\Company\Project` which is `discussable`.

I would like to write:

```
function get_all_discussions($type, $id) 
{
    return Discussion::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->where('discussable_type', $type)
        ->where('discussable_id', $id)
        ->get();
}

get_all_discussion('project', 1232);
```

Unfortunately `->where('discussable_type', $type)` does not work with the morph map.

My current solution is to use this kludge:

```
function getMorphType($typeOrClass)
{
    $morphMap = array_flip(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap());

    return array_get($morphMap, $typeOrClass, $typeOrClass);
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `morphMap` before or after already having instances of `Discussion`? Check your database and see whether the full class name is filled in or just `'project'`. If the full class name is filled in it is probably fixed by replacing the full class names with the shorthand names.

Comment: @Teun `morphMap` is created in my `AppServiceProvider@boot`

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work with the morph map"? The `discussable_type` column already contains "projects" instead of "App\Models\Company\Project", right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A better approach could be defining relationships in the models: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

For example I got Project and Issue, two models that could be discussable.

```
class Project
{
    public function discussions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Discussion::class, 'discussable');
    }
}
```

```
class Issue
{
    public function discussions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Discussion::class, 'discussable');
    }
}
```

Then if you want to get all discussion for a project or an issue:

```
$project = Project::findOrFail(101);
$issue = Issue::findOrFail(102);

$project->discussions;
$issue->discussions;
```